# Cucumber 4.7.2 transform table to row to object

Tags: java, cucumber

I am using JAVA Cucumber 4.7.2

I am transforming data from cucumber tables, into objects/models.

***Cucumber scenario:***

```
  Scenario: test
    Given Create company
      | NAME  | ADDRESS        |
      | Apple | Some address 1 |
```

***Step implementation:***

```
And("^Create company$", (DataTable table) ->
{
    List<Company> companies = table.asList(Company.class);
    companies.forEach(c -> c.createModel());
});
```

***Company model:***

```
public class Company
{
    private String name;
    private String address;
    private Map<String, String> rowData;

    public Company(Map<String, String> rowData)
    {
        this.rowData = rowData;
    }

    public void createModel()
    {
        name = getRowValue("COMPANY");
        address = getRowValue("ADDRESS");
    }

    public String getRowValue(String header)
    {
        String value = rowData.get(header);

        if (Strings.isNullOrEmpty(value))
        {
            throw new NullPointerException("Value for header [" + header + "] is required, but was NULL");
        }
        return value;
    }
}
```

***DataTableConfigurer***

```
public class DataTableConfigurer implements TypeRegistryConfigurer
{
    @Override
    public Locale locale()
    {
        return Locale.ENGLISH;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureTypeRegistry(TypeRegistry registry)
    {
        registry.defineDataTableType(new DataTableType(Company.class, Company::new));
    }
}
```

Now it works fine, data gets loaded from cucumber table, and transformed into model.

I am trying to modify above, to allow ***Company*** model to have empty constructor, and pass ***rowData*** with method, ex:

```
public class Company
{
    private String name;
    private String address;
    private Map<String, String> rowData;

    // no / empty constructor

    /*
     * Passing rowData using method, not by constructor
     */
    public void setRowData(Map<String, String> rowData)
    {
        this.rowData = rowData;
    }

    public String getRowValue(String header)
    {
        String value = rowData.get(header);

        if (Strings.isNullOrEmpty(value))
        {
            throw new NullPointerException("Value for header [" + header + "] is required, but was NULL");
        }
        return value;
    }
}
```

But I could not figure out how to edit ***DataTableConfigurer*** to allow that.

Comment: When passing in a method reference you can always expand it to a lambda. What have you tried so far and why does it not work?

Comment: All my attempts resulted in not working code or syntax errors, could you please provide an example of your solution? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
typeRegistry.defineDataTableType(new DataTableType(Company.class,  (Map<String, String> entry) -> {
    Company o = new Company();
    o.setRowData(entry);
    return o;
}));
```